# Why are certain bridge nodes seeing connectivity problems?

Tags: nodes, tor

When using meek bridges, I see the following in the log files:

```
[WARN] 1 connections have failed: 
3/15/19, 01:06:04.417 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS)   
with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE
```

Yet, Tor will connect fine without a bridge, and I can get it to connect at times with Obfs4 or fte transports (Which give me the same problem but it will eventually connect.)

Could the ISP (Google Fiber) be trying to block the network? or what else might be going on here?

Comment: Your question is not about programming, is it?

Comment: Yes and no. The question is about Tor. and Tor is programming extensive Therefore, anything having to do with Tor has to do with programing to begin with.